# Cannot access value of text using xpath (url)

Tags: php, xpath, meta

I am not able to get text. I need the price `<meta itemprop="price" content="28.99"/>`

Tried with this XPath:

```
    <?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

$urlCT = "https://www.instant-gaming.com/es/834-comprar-key-steam-pro-evolution-soccer-2016/";

$ch = curl_init($urlCT);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$cl = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($cl);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom); 
$xpath->registerXpathNamespace('xhtml' , 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');
$eltitulo = $xpath->query('//xhtml:meta[@itemprop=\"price\"]/@content'); 
$titulo = $eltitulo->item($x)->nodeValue;
echo $titulo;
?>
```

How I can get the price xpath? (28.99€)

Thank you.

Comment: You've shown the desired result, and the code you tried. What was the result you got from that code?

Comment: I'm trying, but does not show me the product price.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the top of the page source, you'll see

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ...>
```

This default namespace declaration says that every descendant of this element that doesn't have an explicit namespace prefix will be in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` namespace. That includes the `<meta>` elements.

Therefore you need to declare a prefix (e.g. `xhtml`) for this namespace, and use it in your XPath expression:

```
$xpath->registerXpathNamespace('xhtml' , 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');
$eltitulo = $xpath->query('//xhtml:meta[@itemprop=\"price\"]/@content');
```

(Note that attributes are not affected by the default namespace, so `@itemprop` for example is not in any namespace, and doesn't need the `xhtml` prefix.)

Comment: Thx for reply :D
if I want this as you would xpath?
//*[@id="ig-product-main-panel-boxprice-contentright-price"]

Comment: @Yunior: You're welcome. Please click the check mark to accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: if I want this as you would xpath xmlns? //*[@id="ig-product-main-panel-boxprice-contentright-price"]

Comment: @Yunior: can you rephrase the question? I don't understand.

Comment: I'm testing and dont shows me the price. I tried your example, but neither. As I can add the xpath? with // * [@ id = "ig-product-main-panel-boxprice-contentright-price"] (copy xpath chrome), i try:

 $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom); 
$xpath->registerXpathNamespace('xhtml' , 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');
$eltitulo = $xpath->query('//xhtml://*[@id="ig-product-main-panel-boxprice-contentright-price"]/text()');  
$titulo = $eltitulo->item($x)->nodeValue;

sorry bad english, i use google translate :/

Comment: @Yunior: It looks like you're trying to do this by trial and error. Learning about XPath will save you a lot of time. Also, the code you showed should give an error message. Pay attention to what it says. When using `*` you don't need to specify a namespace, because `*` matches elements in any namespace. So you can just do `$eltitulo = $xpath->query('//*[@id="ig-product-main-panel-boxprice-contentright-pric‌​e"]/text()');` without any `xhtml:`. However you're using `$x` and I don't know what that is.

Comment: Which would be the right way for me to show the price? It took several days testing and not shows me the store price. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Yunior: What was the result when you tried the code I gave in my answer: `$xpath->registerXpathNamespace('xhtml' , 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');
$eltitulo = $xpath->query('//xhtml:meta[@itemprop=\"price\"]/@content'); ` ? Does it give an error? An empty string?

Comment: I try with: `$xpath->registerXpathNamespace('xhtml' , 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'); 
$eltitulo = $xpath->query('//*[@id="ig-product-main-panel-boxprice-contentright-price"]/text()');` and result empty string, I need to show the price.

Comment: @Yunior: I don't know why it's not showing anything. I'm also confused by the fact that your question was originally about accessing the value of an attribute, but now you're trying to access a text value. However I do see that in your original PHP you were using `\"` to escape double quotes, and you're not doing that now. I don't know which is right (I'm not a PHP expert), but probably one of them is wrong.

Comment: I was confused when writing the title, when I want to get the text (price) of other web if it works, but when xhtml, not detected. It is quite rare. :/

Comment: Maybe PHP does this even if  `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` isn’t in a document？I ask because I know conforming HTML parsers don’t actually pay any attention to that．Instead the HTML spec requires parsers to put the root `html` element of all HTML documents into the HTML namespace．See the *A start tag whose tag name is "html"* step in [12.2.5.4.2 The "before html" insertion mode]( https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#the-before-html-insertion-mode) of the spec．HTML-aware tools just ignore the namespace．But PHP DOMXpath doesn’t？Hazards of using XML tools with HTML…